# Android ) GCM Token Timing Issue at first launch

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, token, android-progressbar

I'm developing a GCM Application.

My issue is that when first install(launch) the app, it takes some time to get GCM token.
But My app just 'POST' to server to register the user.

So at first launch , because of registering when GCM token is null, my app always register GCM token null at first time.

How could I solve this problem?

Actually I tried to solve this by using Progressbar but Progressbar doesn't show like the sample project of GCM provided by google.

How do you guys solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only send the token to your application server after it has been returned by your InstanceID.getToken call which should not happen on the main thread.

You should use an IntentService that will get the token AND send it to your application server, then if necessary, you can use a BroadcastReceiver/LocalBroadcastManager to let your UI know when the the token has been successfully sent to the application server.

Consider the [GCM quickstart sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart). In particular look at the RegistrationIntentService that gets the token and sends it to the server.

```
// [START get_token]
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
// [END get_token]
Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

// TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
sendRegistrationToServer(token);
```

Comment: mmmm i have just had a look at the sample you have put up and the sample i used is telling me to do the sendRegistrationToServer in the DoInBackground of the async task. I like this way though makes more sense

Comment: where are you seeing that instruction could you link?

Comment: i will try and find it again

Comment: Ah no need, either way you can send it using an AsyncTask, however it is not recommended to do it that way, IntentService is much safer :)

Comment: https://github.com/ivanpeng/gcm_demo/blob/master/src/com/ivanpeng/gcmdemo/RegisterApp.java

Answer (score 1):

This should be quite an easy fix. if you followed googles example then the registering to the GCM should be done using an async task class called RegisterApp.

The async task has 3 main methods OnPreExecute, DoInBackground and OnPostExecute. DoInBackground is the method that runs on a seperate thread and that will be why it is failing currently. It hasn't finished running that thread and you have already sent an empty regID to your backend. This wont be failing next time you login to your app because more than likely you are saving the regId to a file and reading it if your app is already registered to the GCM

You can send the regId to your backend in either the DoInBackground, which is where you should be registering to the GCM, or in the OnPostExecute.

I do it in the DoInBackground method straight after it registers as this is the only part that runs on a separate thread and if for some reason it fails to send to my backend it is handled on a seperate thread to the main UIThread.

Dont forget you will also need your current method of sending it because the RegisterApp wont run if your app is already registered.

Hope this helps.

This is the sample i followed. [Here](https://github.com/ivanpeng/gcm_demo/blob/master/src/com/ivanpeng/gcmdemo/RegisterApp.java)

Currently it works for me as the activity that handles the registering is locked to portrait and not much else is going on, but each to their own.

Arthur makes some valid points

Comment: It is not a good idea to make network calls with an AsyncTask, please use something like an IntentService.

Comment: Hi Arthur, you have me worried now, what are the dangers of doing this

Comment: AsyncTask is meant for FAST background tasks, network is not considered fast. It has the potential to leak activities eg if the user rotates the screen during execution of AsyncTask, see this Alex Lockwood post on some of the pitfalls that you can run into when using AsyncTask. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html